# Linear Independence Solving for $h$

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of h will the vectors

$v_1 = (h , -1/2, -1/2)$,
$v_2 = (-1/2, h, -1/2)$,
$v_3 = (-1/2, -1/2, h)$

form a linearly dependent set?

There are apparently two answers for $h$ here. I think one of them is $-1/2$, but what is the other?

Comment: The other is apparently $1$. But, what have you tried to get a solution?

Comment: I have tried to use inspection simply to check which of them are multiples. Why does 1 work?

Comment: Because the vectors sum to $(0,0,0)$ if $h=1$.

Comment: Thanks! The conceptual help is invaluable. Thank you user2097!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a linearly dependent set if and only if the matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
h    & -1/2 & -1/2 \\
-1/2 & h    & -1/2 \\
-1/2 & -1/2 & h
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies $\det A=0$. Since
$$
\det A=\frac{1}{4}(h-1)(2h+1)^2
$$
it follows that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a linearly dependent set if and only if $h=1$ or $\displaystyle h=-\frac{1}{2}$.